# Django: Tastypie: Updating record after displaying it

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a very simple model:

```
class challenge(models.Model):
    challenge = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField('date published',null=True,blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And that model is linked via Tastypie.

By default the timestamp field is empty when you add an entry.

I would like to update the timestamp field with the time that the user first accessed the resource.

For example, if admin added data is:

```
Challenge: Do something
Timestamp: Null
Code: 123
```

Then after accessing `/api/challenge/1/?format=json` to have the output be:

```
{"challenge": "Do something", "code": "sasdasd", "id": 2, "resource_uri": "/api/challenge/2/", "timestamp": "2015-05-11T12:18:54"}
```

Is this possible using Tastypie and how?

Comment: When is `11/11/11 22:22:22`? Is that the time a user accesses the resource? Can you show us your API code?

Comment: Ok, I was typing that out off the top of my head, output is : {"challenge": "Do something", "code": "sasdasd", "id": 2, "resource_uri": "/api/challenge/2/", "timestamp": "2015-05-11T12:18:54"}

Comment: API code right now is just:

class challengeResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = challenge.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'challenge'